# Как подключить к проекту шаблон "Windows(WPF)"?

Tags: wpf

Написал простенькую программу на C#, используя шаблон "Empty Project" в VisualStudio 2019. С удивлением обнаружил, что не могу подключить шаблон "Windows(WPF)" его нет в списке шаблонов: папка проекта/добавить/создать элемент.
Как подключить к проекту шаблон "Windows(WPF)"?
Вот скриншот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Visual Studio Installer разработка под десктоп выбрана?

Comment: А это необходимо? Когда при создании проекта выбираешь шаблон App(WPF), то шаблон "Windows(WPF)" доступен.

Comment: Приложите скриншот, где чего не хватает

Comment: А как добавить? При попытке прикрепить скриншот пишет: "Отсутствует тело сообщения".

Comment: Нажмите править под сообщением, потом кнопку для загрузки изображения

Comment: Так и делал, при нажатии на кнопку сохранить изменения, пишет "Отсутствует тело сообщения"